# Pandas Dataframe can't loc columns with different datatypes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with different datatypes across columns (but the same datatype within each column). When I try to loc some new data  into row 0, the first row gets replaced with the column names.

This does not happen when the columns are all the same datatype, however.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

test = pd.DataFrame({'int':[0],
    'float':[0.],
    'str':['z'],})
test.loc[(0)] = {
    'int':0,
    'float':0.1,
    'str':'a',}
test.loc[(1)] = {
    'int':1,
    'float':1.1,
    'str':'b',}

test2 = pd.DataFrame({'float0':[0.],
    'float1':[0.],
    'float2':[0.],})
test2.loc[(0)] = {
    'float0':0.,
    'float1':0.1,
    'float2':0.2,}
test2.loc[(1)] = {
    'float0':1.0,
    'float1':1.1,
    'float2':1.2,}
```

```py
print(test.to_string())

   int  float  str
0  int  float  str
1    1    1.1    b

print(test2.to_string())

   float0  float1  float2
0     0.0     0.1     0.2
1     1.0     1.1     1.2
```

Comment: Apparently, repeating `test.loc[(0)] = {
    'int':0,
    'float':0.1,
    'str':'a',}` two times corrects it!!

Comment: @hacker315 ahh you're right. I see the problem now.

Comment: @hacker315 that's a creative (yet odd) solution that works, thanks!

Comment: @MohitMotwani sorry I accidentally deleted your first comment, but yes the apparent print error comes from the output, not me.